# Using custom editor in ASP.NET Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

Is it possible i use some WYSIWYG editors like TinyMCE or FCK Editor instead of MultiLine Textbox for ASP.NET Dynamic Data?

The default object is a server side object but i want to use a client side objects that working ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create custom Field Template MultiLineEditor_Edit.ascx (copy from MultilineText_Edit.ascx Field Template) and then add to MultiLineEditor_Edit.ascx, for example, [HTMLEditorExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HtmlEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx).

Then edit your metadata:

```
[UIHint("MultiLineEditor")]
public object ColumnName { get; set; }
```

For more information please read article [How to: Customize ASP.NET Dynamic Data Default Field Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488533%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).